# How to pause the movement of the circle upon clicking the screen?

Tags: java, animation, geometry

I want to pause the circle's movement when I click in the GUI. It currently moves from right to left and can be dragged which is not what i want. Thanks in advance!

The first class creates the circle, the second paints it, and the third is the main method.

```
/*
 * This program creates an animation for a circle.
 */

package circle.animation;

import java.awt.*;

/*
 * @author talhaiqbal18
 */

public class CircleAnimation
{
    private int centerX, centerY, radius;
    private Color color;
    private int direction, speed;
    private boolean filled;

    public CircleAnimation(int x, int y, int r, Color c) {
        centerX = x;
        centerY = y;
        radius = r;
        color = c;
        direction = 0;
        speed = 0;
        filled = false;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        if (filled)
            g.fillOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        else
            g.fillOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    public void fill(Graphics g) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    public boolean containsPoint(int x, int y) {
       int xSquared = (x - centerX) * (x - centerX);
       int ySquared = (y - centerY) * (y - centerY);
       int radiusSquared = radius * radius;
       return xSquared + ySquared - radiusSquared <= 0;
    }

    public void move(int xAmount, int yAmount) {
        centerX = centerX + xAmount;
        centerY = centerY + yAmount;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int s) {
        speed = s;
    }

    public void setDirection(int d) {
        direction = d % 360;
    }

    public void turn(int degrees) {
        direction = (direction + degrees) % 360;
    }

    public void move() {
        move((int)(speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(direction))),
            (int)(speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction))));
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean b) {
        filled = b;
    }
}

/*
 * This is the color panel class for the circle animation project.
 */

package circle.animation;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/*
 * @author talhaiqbal18
 */

public class ColorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private CircleAnimation circle;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private CircleAnimation selectedCircle;
    private int x, y;

    public ColorPanel(Color backColor, int width, int height) {
        setBackground(backColor);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        circle = new CircleAnimation(350, height / 2, 350, Color.blue);
        circle.setDirection(180);
        circle.setSpeed(6);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1, new MoveListener());
        timer.start();
        addMouseListener(new PanelListener());
        addMouseMotionListener(new PanelMotionListener());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        circle.fill(g);
    }

    private class MoveListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x = circle.getX();
            int radius = circle.getRadius();
            int width = getWidth();
            if (x - radius <= 0 || x + radius >= width) {
                circle.turn(180);
            }
            circle.move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private class PanelListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            if (circle.containsPoint(x, y))
                selectedCircle = circle;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Object selectedcircle = null;
        }
    }   
    private class PanelMotionListener extends MouseMotionAdapter
    {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
                int newX = e.getX();
                int newY = e.getY();
                int dx = newX - x;
                int dy = newY - y;
            if (selectedCircle != null) {
                selectedCircle.move(dx,dy);
                x = newX;
                y = newY;
                repaint(); }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * This is the main method which will implement the actions of the previous classes.
 */

package circle.animation;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/*
 * @author talhaiqbal18
 */

public class MainMethod
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame theGUI  = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("Circle Animation");
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(Color.white, 100, 100);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();
        pane.add(panel);
        theGUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following method `mouseClicked` to your PanelListener:

```
  private class PanelListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      x = e.getX();
      y = e.getY();
      if (circle.containsPoint(x, y)) selectedCircle = circle;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      // nothing here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
      if (timer.isRunning()) {
        timer.stop();
      } else {
        timer.start();
      }
    }
  }
```

BTW I had to change something in your code to make it run - removed "int" before `x = circle.getX();`

private class MoveListener implements ActionListener {

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      x = circle.getX();
      int radius = circle.getRadius();
      int width = getWidth();
      if (x - radius <= 0 || x + radius >= width) {
        circle.turn(180);
      }
      circle.move();
      repaint();
    }
  }
```